# Powershell script to check and then add multiple drivers

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, printing, driver

I want to preload known printer drivers from a server share to devices enrolled with Intune

The below works for the first item in the array when run locally, how do I do this for multiple array items?

```
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName = "DriverName2 PCL6"; DriverPath = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER2"; DriverInf = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER2\FILE2.INF" }
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName = "DriverName3 PCL6"; DriverPath = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER3"; DriverInf = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER3\FILE3.INF" }
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName = "DriverName4 PCL6"; DriverPath = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER4"; DriverInf = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER4\FILE4.INF" }
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName = "DriverName5 PCL6"; DriverPath = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER5"; DriverInf = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER5\FILE5.INF" }

#Check Printer Driver Exists Then Add Driver

foreach ($Driver in $PrinterDriver) {
    $PrintDiverExists = Get-PrinterDriver -name $PrinterDriver[0].DriverName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($printDiverExists) {
        Write-Warning "Printer Driver Already Present"
    }
    else {
        cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -m $PrinterDriver[0].DriverName -h $PrinterDriver[0].DriverPath -i $PrinterDriver[0].DriverInf
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code try changing all your `$PrinterDriver[0]` to `$driver`

Comment: Thanks @Itchydon that works a treat!